# Format string vulnerability exploit in 64 bits systems

Tags: linux, security

I am studying the format string vulnerability on my 64-bit ubuntu 14.04 machine.

The code is very simple:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int target = 0;

 void vuln(char *buffer)
 {

   printf(buffer);
   printf("%i", target);
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   vuln(argv[1]);
 }
```

My final goal is to change value of the variable target, but I am stuck at the very fisrt step: finding the offset of the string in memory.

What I am doing is:

```
./format2 `perl -e 'print "AAAAAAAA" . "%p."x500'` | grep 414141
```

And sometimes the string is present (I can see the 41s string), but sometimes is not. So my question is, shouldn't the offset of the string be always the same?

EDIT: after some research I find out that the string is stored right before the environment variables, which are mapped by the kernel for every process. It may be the case that due to ALSR these pages have different addresses every time?

Answer (score -2):

As you wrote, the string is stored at the beginning of the stack, after some other values. ASLR (address space layout randomization) does not change the offset, it changes the starting point.

If you want to demonstrate this vulnerability, switching off ASLR is a good idea.

However there seems to be other issues too trying to exploit this weakness. That is, you can't write zeroes into memory with this method, as the printf will treat any zeroes as end-of-string and will stop there. Thus the address where you want to write to must not have leading zero bytes. This issue is already mentioned in http://www.thenewsh.com/%7Enewsham/format-string-attacks.pdf. Any idea how to circumvent this issue?